# How to deal with many to many relationships for specific use case in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_professions
  has_many :professions, through: :user_professions

  has_many :interested_professions, -> { where(interested:true) }, class_name: "UserProfession"
end

class UserProfession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession
end

class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_professions
end
```

The user - profession relationship is kind of fixed, so the user has for instance 3 associated professions. These can't change and are assigned programatically. Simple so far.

What I now would like to do, is use the same join table to manage also a list of professions the user is interested in. I think i should be able to do this through the same relationship.

For this specific relationship, I need to either update the interested atteribute if the relation already exists, or create a new relation in the UserProfession table. I'm only stuck in how to do the form.

I tried this:

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  - @professions.each do |p|
    = f.simple_fields_for :professions, p do |prof|
      = prof.simple_fields_for :user_professions, @user.user_professions.find_or_initialize_by(profession: p) do |user_prof|
        = user_prof.input :id
        = user_prof.input :interested, as: :boolean, label: s.description
  = f.submit
```

Rails give me an error when trying to submit the form though, which I don't really understand:

```
Couldn't find Profession with ID=1 for User with ID=5
```

Which is correct, but in this case Rails should create a new record for it.

Any ideas?